# header time with cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-1.2

someone ask this quesion but no answer solved this problem

header("refresh:5; url='pagetoredirect.php'");

we can use this if we want to redirect our page in 5 second ,

is there any way to redirect page in 5 second in cakephp ?

if yes please let me know

i tried this code but not work
**/app/controllers/examples_controller.php**

```
?php
    class ExamplesController extends AppController
    {
        public $name = "Examples";
        ...
        public function someAction( ){
            ...
            $url = array( 'controller' => 'examples', 'action' => 'someOtherAction' );
            $this->set( 'url', $url );
            $this->header( "refresh:5; url='".Router::url( $url )."'" );
        }
        ...
    }
?>
```

**/app/views/examples/some_action.ctp**

```
<p class='notice'>
    <?php echo $this->Html->link( "You are being redirected to ".Router::url( $url )." in 5 seconds. If you do not wish to wait click here.", $url ); ?>
</p>
```

Comment: That should do it, although without quotes around the url. What does "not work" mean? Do you get an error? Are the headers not set?

Comment: this error sent Notice (8): Undefined variable: url [APP\views\books\add.ctp, line 13]

Comment: @fakhrawy I have tried the same http://stackoverflow.com/a/7260191/4380588 and this worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using a [flash](http://book.cakephp.org/view/983/flash) command.

Like redirect(), the flash() method is used to direct a user to a new page after an operation. The flash() method is different in that it shows a message before passing the user on to another URL.

The first parameter should hold the message to be displayed, and the second parameter is a CakePHP-relative URL. CakePHP will display the $message for $pause seconds before forwarding the user on.

If there's a particular template you'd like your flashed message to use, you may specify the name of that layout in the $layout parameter.

For in-page flash messages, be sure to check out SessionComponent’s setFlash() method.

What I think is that you can set no message so the flash command would just redirect after a desired number of secods.

Comment: can you give me just  one example

Comment: @fakhrawy Did my answer satisfy your question? If yes, please accept.